# show more details of the person/group in list column

Tags: 2010, list

I am making an Issue list in Sharepoint 2010, where the issue can be assigned to "Person or Group". I have to show more details of the person(assigned to)eg. Name, Office and phone etc.. in (another column or same column) in the list. By default Sharepoint let us choose only one value in "Show Field".
Could you please point what are the possibilities to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

In 2007 I had to do this on a few occasions. My approach was to create additional person/group fields set to display the proper field and use a workflow to copy the person into the other fields. The downfall of this approach is that while the Sharepoint UI might display the department, if you need to use that say in a workflow, it will provide you with the domain\username.

There is a workflow feature on [Codeplex](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lookup%20user%20info) that would allow you to query for the user information and then update text fields with the data.

Another option would be to do it with jQuery/[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) on the new item form that when a user is added, you query for the user properties and store them in hidden fields on your form.